# Trying to write a query that will display duplicates results as null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like the first example.
I'm trying to write a MSSQL2012 statement that that will display results like the second example.

Basically I want null values instead of duplicate values in columns 1 and 2.  This is for readability purposes during reporting.

This seems like it should be possible, but I'm drawing a blank.  No amount of joins or unions I've written has rendered the results I need.

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |    4 |
| 1    | 2    |    5 |
| 1    | 3    |    6 |
| 1    | 3    |    7 |
+------+------+------+


| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |    4 |
| Null | null |    5 |
| null | 3    |    6 |
| null | null |    7 |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Typically this would be handled in the report itself -- e.g. if you're using SSRS, then you would group on `Col1` and `Col2` and show their values only once. This would be quite difficult in SQL itself.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with no subqueries at all:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2, col3) = 1
             then col1
        end) as col1,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col3) = 1
             then col2
        end) as col2,
       col3
from t
order by t.col1, t.col2, t.col3;
```

Note that the `order by` at the end of the query is very important.  The result set that you want depends critically on the ordering of the rows.  Without the `order by`, the result set could be in any order.  So, the query might look like it works, and then suddenly fail one day or on a slightly different set of data.

Comment: Upvote for the note on `order by`, I should have included that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a   [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**:

```
;with cte as (
select *
  , rn_1 = row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2, col3)
  , rn_2 = row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3)
from t
)
select 
    col1 = case when rn_1 > 1 then null else col1 end
  , col2 = case when rn_2 > 1 then null else col2 end
  , col3
from cte
```

without the `cte`

```
select 
    col1 = case when rn_1 > 1 then null else col1 end
  , col2 = case when rn_2 > 1 then null else col2 end
  , col3
from (
  select *
    , rn_1 = row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2, col3)
    , rn_2 = row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3)
  from t
  ) sub
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/UYA17142

returns:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |    4 |
| NULL | NULL |    5 |
| NULL | 3    |    6 |
| NULL | NULL |    7 |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Your answers delivered exactly what I needed.  Thank you for you time and input!